# Comparing variable to Math.max(...arr) not returning accurate answer

Tags: arrays, loops, if-statement, max

I'm trying to complete an easy LeetCode question: https://leetcode.com/problems/kids-with-the-greatest-number-of-candies/ but cannot figure out why my code is not working correctly. Here is the question and a correct solution:

> Given the array candies and the integer extraCandies, where candies[i] represents the number of candies that the ith kid has.For each kid check if there is a way to distribute extraCandies among the kids such that he or she can have the greatest number of candies among them. Notice that multiple kids can have the greatest number of candies.

> > Input: candies = [2,3,5,1,3], extraCandies = 3
> > Output: [true,true,true,false,true]

Here is my current code:

```
var kidsWithCandies = function(candies, extraCandies) {
    
    let newArr = [];
    const max = Math.max(...candies)
    
    for(i=0; i<candies.length; i++) {
        let newVal = candies[i] + extraCandies
        
        if (newVal >= max) {
            newArr.push('true')
        } else {
            newArr.push('false')
        }
    }
    
    return newArr
};
```

My code is returning [true,true,true,true,true] instead of [true,true,true,false,true].

I've used console.log() to check the values for 'max' and 'newVal' as the loop runs, and they are all correct, so there must be something wrong with my if statement, but I can't figure out what.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Works for me. https://jsfiddle.net/ychj41ub/

Comment: Thanks for sending -- you're right, it works everywhere but LeetCode. I removed the quotes around true and false and it worked. I guess they weren't looking for true/false as strings

Answer (score 1):

You've answered your own question. Nonetheless, this'd also pass on LeetCode:

```
const kidsWithCandies = (candies, extraCandies) => {
    let maxCandies = 0;
    const greatest = [];

    for (const candy of candies) {
        (candy > maxCandies) && (maxCandies = candy);
    }

    for (let index = 0; index < candies.length; ++index) {
        greatest.push(candies[index] + extraCandies >= maxCandies);
    }
    return greatest;
};
```